# How do we Initialize a List type property on a structure? in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, properties, initialization, structure

This is the structure  im trying to work with:

```
Public Structure Point
        Public Property id As Integer
        Public Property x As Integer
        Public Property y As Integer

        Public Property Points As List(Of Point)

        Public ReadOnly Property key As String
            Get
                Return x & "," & y
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub Add(t As Point)
            If Points Is Nothing Then
                Points = New List(Of Point)
            End If
            Points.Add(t)
        End Sub
End Structure
```

The following code below is an attempt to use the Point Structure:

```
Dim l = New List(Of Point)
Dim t = new Point 'test point

l.Add(t)
l(l.Count - 1).Add(t)
```

Looking at l(0).Points in the locals window, the property is always Nothing.

Why is this?

**SOLVED**: seems the following code works:

```
Public Structure Point
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property x As Integer
    Public Property y As Integer

    Private _points As List(Of Point)
    Public ReadOnly Property Points() As List(Of Point)
        Get
            If _points Is Nothing Then
                _points = New List(Of Point)
            End If

            Return _points
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property key As String
        Get
            Return x & "," & y
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Add(t As Point)
        If _points Is Nothing Then
            _points = New List(Of Point)
        End If
        _points.Add(t)
    End Sub
End Structure
```

usage:

```
Dim l = New List(Of Point)
Dim t = new Point 'test point

t.add(t)
l.Add(t)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the error you talk about is a `NullReferenceException`, and the solution is to create an instance before accessing using the `New` keyword.

You already do this in the `Add` method, but you should create the instance in the constructor.

Also, you should probably use a `Class` if you don't have good reasons to use a mutable `Structure`.

---

In response to your edit:

> ```
> Dim l = New List(Of Point)
> Dim t = new Point 'test point
>
> l.Add(t)
> l(l.Count - 1).Add(t)
> ```
>
> Looking at l(0).Points in the locals window, the property is always
>   Nothing.
>
> Why is this?

That's why I said don't use a mutable `Structure` if you don't have good reasons to.

If you call `l.Add(t)`, *a copy* of `t` will be added to `l`.

When you access a `Point` item via `l(l.Count - 1).Add(t)`, you create *another copy* of the `Point`, then add *another copy* of `t` to that *second copy*.

`Add` is called on the *second copy* of `t`. When you look at `l(0)`, you actually see *a copy* of the *first copy* of `t`.

If that is not the behaviour you want, use a `class`.

Comment: The strange this is that, trying to use this structure, i call the add  method to add a few points to the Points List. The local window in the  debugger always returns Points = nothing

Comment: I need each point to be mutable. i.e. dim P as new Point, and Dim T=P If i set T.x=0, it must not affect P.x

Comment: @CharlesO If you create an instance of Points, then when you'll do T=P they will both have the same instance of the list.

Comment: true...but it is always nothing, even after calling Add. 
Dont take my word for it ... put it in your local window as see what i mean.

Comment: That's why I said don't use a mutable `Structure` if you don't have good reasons to. If you call `l.Add(t)`, *a copy* of `t` will be added to `l`. When you access a `Point` item via `l(l.Count - 1).Add(t)`, you create *another copy* of the `Point`, then add *another copy* of `t` to that *second copy*. `Add` is called on the *second copy* of `t`. When you look at `l(0)`, you actually see *a copy* of the *first copy* of `t`. If that is not the behaviour you want, use a `class`.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you access the point property you need to check if it's Nothing like you did in the add function.

Your best bet would be to put a constructor to initialize the list (you might need to change it to a class). You could also have a initialize function that would be class everytime you create a new instance.

```
Public Structure Point

        Public Sub Initialize()
            Points = New List(Of Point)
        End Sub

        ...

End Structure
```

I just notice the other comment. You could just have a property that initialize a private variable if it's still Nothing.

```
    Private _points As List(Of Point)

    Public ReadOnly Property Points() As List(Of Point)
        Get
            If _points Is Nothing Then
                _points = New List(Of Point)
            End If

            Return _points
        End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: @CharlesO What I mean is everytime you create an instance of a Point you call Initialize right after.

Comment: @CharlesO I added something else to my answer

Comment: i have modified my question to include a sample usage scenario. Why does the Locals window always report the Property Points as Nothing even after initializing and adding several points using the Add method?

Comment: @CharlesO Your new example won't work, when you do l(l.Count - 1) it gets a new copy of your object then add a point. It does not update the one on the list. You'll have to insert it back to the list after.

Comment: you are correct, that's why i not use t.add(t) then i call l.add(t). This works fine now. thanks.